# Executing stored procedure with Output return in with PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2 per below:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[addlotDred] @inlot varchar(10), @inWafer varchar(3) ,@inlayer 
varchar(10), @returned int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @lotAdded int

EXEC dbo.addLotPullEdi @lot = @inlot, @wafer = @inWafer,  @layer = @inlayer

SET @lotAdded = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.waferEdi WHERE lot = @inlot AND wafer = 
    @inWafer AND layer = @inlayer)

IF @lotAdded > 0
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.pullNcdd

    EXEC dbo.pullCoordinatesServerInfo

    EXEC dbo.pullSPCComments

    EXEC dbo.updateDate

    EXEC dbo.pullWipComments

    EXEC dbo.pullExperimentComments

    EXEC dbo.pullYodaComments

    EXEC dbo.pullQef

    EXEC dbo.pullDrb

    EXEC dbo.pullTracers

    SET @returned = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @returned = 0
END
END
```

I wish to execute this SP with PHP and use the Output results to feed back to an AJAX query.  When I run the SP in SSMS it executes and returns the value I expect (this has been updated from my original post)  PHP:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=(local);Database=dred");
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
    PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error connecting to the server.");
}

 $sth = $dbh->prepare("DECLARE @returned EXEC dbo.addlotDred ?,?,?,?");

//for testing purpose, these would usually come from AJAX call
$retval = "@returned OUTPUT";
$lot = 'Z12C1111';
$wafer = 'yyy';
$layer = 'xxx';

$sth->bindParam(1,$lot,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(2,$wafer,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(3,$layer,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(4,$retval,PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);

try {
    $sth->execute();
    $results = array();
    do{
        $results[] = $sth->fetchAll();
    } while ($sth->nextRowset());
  }catch (PDOException $e) {
  die("Error adding to the database.");
}

echo $results;
```

PHP has been updated slightly to DECLARE @returned and to add PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING per my comment.  Now the PHP runs but returns an empty array (with and without the DECLARE @returned added to the query).  Again, any advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Interesting, when I add PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING as an attribute to the query the query executes.  I get a null array, which I need to troubleshoot, but it's a step in the right direction I think.

Comment: I was not able to get the return value to work using the recommendation below.  I tried several other suggestions found through search but none worked.  As a work around I altered the stored procedure to NOT return a value, and then added one more PHP call to perform the validation that I was performing to for my return value.  Less than elegant but it works for now.